# How do I print a book (A6 size), 4 times into an A4 size paper?

Tags: paper-size, printing

I have a latex prepared doublesided pdf, it has 130 pages. 
I just want a result where I can cut the A4 paper into 4 parts and get 4 separate a6 books. No need to set frames, just cut the paper in each half.

I now there are many instructions on how to insert certain size page into a pdf of other size, but none gives instructions on how to place the same document multiplied by four and with this x4 page order on each page.

So, the first A4 page should be seen with 4 times the first a6 page, and the second page the same, and so on.

1st page (with 4 a6 sized print)

- [1][1]
- [1][1]

2nd page (with 4 a6 sized print)

- [2][2]
- [2][2]

etc.

Comment: The most flexible command-line tool I know to arrange pages is the `psbook` utility that works on PostScript files (which you could produce with `latex` and `dvips`). Another one is `cpdf` that works on PDF files. However, I don't have a solution ready.

Comment: Actually, \includegraphics has an undocumented feature [page=...] which could be used here.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianLindig, I requested to `cpdf` by e-mail. Even when I couldn't implement the full command John Whitington gave me this answer, which may be helpful to others: _If you don't need to preserve PDF elements like hyperlinks, and it's
just for printing, **one option is to convert to PostScript, and then use
psnup, and convert back to PDF.**_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0pt,nofoot,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\fourplay}[2]% #1 = page number (text), #2 = file name
{\pagebreak\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}\par
\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}\includegraphics[page=#1]{#2}\par}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt
\begin{document}
\loop\fourplay{\thepage}{test5.pdf}
\ifnum\value{page}<2\relax \repeat% 2=number of pages
\end{document}
```

where the file test5.pdf was created using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hurray!! Many many thanks! At 1st I didn't quite get the code on how to handle proper number of pages (here set to 2). Just checked and changed a line and good to go: \ifnum\value{page}<130\relax